# Deploying test flask API in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, api, flask, postman, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy example flask API app given in flask document in pythonanywhere.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


todos = {}

class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I was testing this app locally in pycharm, I executed app successfully by sending data using

```
curl http://localhost:5000/todo1 -d "data=Remember the milk" -X PUT
```

command in pycharm terminal.

The result I got is

> {
>       "todo1": "Remember the milk"
>   }

But when I tested the deployment using Postman the result I got is

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Parameters used in Query params in Postman are:
key:data
value:"Remember the milk"

The result got when executed the app in locally is the correct result.
What am I doing wrong?

**PS:** 
When using the pythonanywhere I used

```
http://www.mydomain.pythonanywhere.com
```

Comment: What url were you using in the second case? Of course you have to use a pythonanywhere url instead of localhost.

Comment: Yes I did that. Sorry if I wasn't clear. The mentioned error caused when I used 'http://mydomain.pythonanywhere.com/'

Comment: You used http://www.mydomain.pythonanywhere.com/todo1 right?

Comment: Yes @Ardweaden. The differences I made when using deployment are using my domain url and using postman to send requests.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right URL?   Above you confirmed that you used `mydomain.pythonanywhere.com/todo1`, but you've edited your question to say that you used `www.mydomain.pythonanywhere.com/todo1`.   The second URL will not work, you need to use the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data has to be send in 'Body' tab, not in 'Param' tab.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `http://localhost:5000/` with the url from pythonanywhere, e.g.
`http://yourusername.pythonanywhere.com`
That is assuming you didn't pay and configure your own domain

Comment: Yes I did that. Sorry if I wasn't clear. The mentioned error caused when I used http://mydomain.pythonanywhere.com/